# 11ty - How to display post tags in my post.njk file?

Tags: tags, blogs, posts, nunjucks, eleventy

I've used the 11ty/eleventy-base-blog template and have things working well - but I am trying to display the tags nicely within my post.njk file.

At the top of my post (.md) file I have this:

```
tags: ['Tag 1', 'Tag 2']
```

Within _includes/layouts/postslist.njk I'm using the following code:

```
{% for tag in post.data.tags %}
  {%- if collections.tagList.indexOf(tag) != -1 -%}
  {% set tagUrl %}/tags/{{ tag }}/{% endset %}
    <span class="tag">{{ tag }}</span>
  {%- endif -%}
{% endfor %}
```

This template is then used in the index.njk file (my homepage) using this code:

```
{% set postslist = collections.posts | head(-3) %}
{% set postslistCounter = collections.posts | length %}
{% include "postslist.njk" %}
```

The output of this is:

```
<span class="tag">Tag 1</span>
<span class="tag">Tag 2</span>
```

However, if I use `{{ tags }}` in my post.njk file I get the following output:

```
posts,Tag 1,Tag 2
```

I have also tried using the same code from the 'postslist.njk' file and putting it in my 'post.njk' file but that doesn't work.

How can I display the tags on my post in separated 'span' tags and also remove the 'posts' tag?

If you want me to open up my git repo then let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the repo?

Comment: I've just made it public here: https://github.com/chrisbratt/bratt.co

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Why is the `posts` tag in your tags?

In the starter template you're using ([11ty/eleventy-base-blog](https://github.com/11ty/eleventy-base-blog/commit/496982355eaf654d3ab3805c0b6640aca3286186)), the `posts/` directory includes a [directory data file](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/data-template-dir/) ([posts.json](https://github.com/11ty/eleventy-base-blog/blob/v5.0.2/posts/posts.json)), which gets applied too all files in that directory – i.e. to all posts. Since the [.eleventy.js config file](https://github.com/11ty/eleventy-base-blog/blob/v5.0.2/.eleventy.js#L14) uses the [Data Deep Merge option](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/data-deep-merge/), the tags you set in each post get merged with the `posts` tag. This is why the tags of your post are `['posts', 'Tag 1', 'Tag 2']`.

You can solve this in multiple ways. Either use two different frontmatter fields for collection and display purposes, or just filter out the `posts` tag when displaying the tags of a post.

### How to output a list of tags?

If you just do `{{ tags }}`, you're telling Nunjucks to output an array, so it has to figure out how to convert an array to a string. Apparently, the default behaviour in this case is to simply join them with commas. You can make this more explicit (and include a space after the comma while you're at it):

```
{{ posts | join(', ') }}
```

Or, if you want to wrap the items in HTML tags, you can use a loop, optionally with a [joiner](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html#joiner-separator):

```
{% set comma = joiner() %}
{% for tag in tags -%}
  {% if tag !== 'posts' %}
    {{ comma() }} <span class="tag">{{ tag }}</span>
  {% endif %}
{%- endfor %}
```

Comment: This is helpful, thanks. How do I filter out the posts tag?

Comment: @ChristopherBratt I would probably go with the first approach, i.e. use two different fields to sort posts into collections and for display purposes. Alternatively, you can use a [computed property](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/data-computed/) to generate something like `publicTags`, which just copies all tags except the `posts` tag. Or even just check in the loop if the current tag is `posts` and skip it.

Comment: I think I'd rather simply filter out the 'posts' tag for now but I'm not sure how to do this. Any pointers would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @ChristopherBratt I've updated the last code example with an if-condition that makes the loop skip the posts tag.